# application.html.haml not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I am using rails version 3.2.12 and was using .erb templates for my view.

Now I want to start using haml templates.

I added haml and haml-rails to the gem file and installed the bundle.

```
Using haml (4.0.0) 
Installing haml-rails (0.4)
```

I have made a mock-up application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Rotten Potatoes!
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    = yield
```

I then changed the application_controller.rb to

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout "application"
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

when I run this I get the following error message:
Missing template layouts/application with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/coen/Desktop/rails_project/sample_app/app/views"

it seems as if the haml handler not installed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, have you restarted your development server? It is very important thing to do after adding a gem to Gemfile.

BTW. I use haml all the time, i haven't ever used 'haml-rails'.

When i start fresh project, the only thing i do is add "gem 'haml'" to Gemfile and everything works just like it supposed to work.

Comment: Arggh, I hate it when could have thought of the answer myself :)
Thanks a bundle mate!